# Le « marigot » : précisions, expression, autres toponymes substantivés ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, substantivation, toponymes

[image]

<sup>*Histoire generale des isles de S. Christophe, de la Guadeloupe, de la Martinique, et autres dans l'Amerique : où l'on verra l'establissement des colonies françoises, dans ces isles; leurs guerres ciuiles & etrangeres, & tout ce qui se passe dans les voyages & retours des Indes : comme aussi plusieurs belles particularitez des Antilles de l'Amerique, une description generale de l'isle de la Guadeloupe: de tous ses mineraux, de ses pierreries, de ses riuieres, fontaines & estangs; & de toutes ses plantes : de plus, la description de tous les animaux de la mer, de l'air, & de la terre: & un traité fort ample des moeurs des Sauuages du pays, de l'estat de la colonie françoise, & des [esclaues](http://www.unesco.org/new/fr/communication-and-information/flagship-project-activities/memory-of-the-world/register/full-list-of-registered-heritage/registered-heritage-page-7/registry-of-slaves-of-the-british-caribbean-1817-1834/#c190216), tant Mores, que Sauuages*, [Jean Baptiste Du Tertre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Baptiste_Du_Tertre), 1654</sup>

---

Le *marigot* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marigot), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/marigot/49483?q=marigot#49390), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marigot), [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/marigot), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17570107)) est un mot français des Antilles, qui provient du toponyme *Anse du Marigot* sur l'île de Saint-Christophe (aujourd'hui [*Saint-Christophe-et-Niévès*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Christophe_(%C3%AEle))) du temps de la [colonie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Christophe_(colonie_fran%C3%A7aise)) française (1625-1702) et on l'[atteste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/marigot) en 1654 sur la carte qui précède dans l'[oeuvre](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k114023b/f18.image) de *Du Tertre*. On ne sait pas exactement comment s'est formé le mot *marigot*, et on dit souvent qu'il est « peut-être issu d'un croisement entre mare et un mot caraïbe » (TLFi). Il s'agit, surtout sur le continent africain (1688), du « petit marais tropical, bras mort de rivière ou de fleuve » ou de « tout point d’eau alimenté par les pluies, les débordements d’un fleuve ou des nappes souterraines » (Wiktionnaire) : « Je parviens au bord d'un marigot aux eaux abondantes. Sur l'autre rive, des jappements que je reconnais pour ceux des cynocéphales » (Gide, *Retour du Tchad*).

---

Par ailleurs *Wiktionnaire* présente un emploi qu'on ne trouve pas ailleurs, avec une citation contemporaine :

> [...]
>   (Familier) Groupe de personnes se livrant une compétition occulte pour
>   le pouvoir.
>
> *J’ai connu voici un quart de siècle un jeune homme, sans doute énarque
>   ou au minimum polytechnicien, tombé par hasard dans un **marigot
>   politique** et qui fut dépêché dans quelque coin d’Anjou pour s’y
>   approprier une circonscription vacante.* — (Philippe Alexandre, *Mon livre de cuisine politique*, 1992)
>
> [ *Wiktionnaire*, [*marigot*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marigot) ]

---

- A-t-on plus de précisions sur la formation ou l'origine du mot
  *marigot* ?
- Le marigot politique (Wiktionnaire), est-ce une nouvelle extension de sens de *marigot*, d'où ça vient ; est-ce la raison pour laquelle on a traduit le propos d'un politicien (*drain the swamp*) par *curer le marigot* ; *curer le marigot* est-ce une expression usuelle en France ?
- Hormis l'*appellation d'origine contrôlée*, connaît-on d'autres
  **toponymes** qui sont utilisés comme des *noms communs* tel que le *marigot* ?

Comment: Au fait, il y a un quartier de Vieux-Habitants, à Guadeloupe, qui s'appelle Morne Marigot.

Answer (score 1):

- [X]
- - En français, il y a de nombreuses allégories par rapport au milieu politique et au champ lexical des choses sales, visqueuses et qui sentent... Outre la m* et autres déchets, l'idée du marécage ne m'en semble pas si éloignée que ça.
  - *"drain the swamp"* = "drainer le marais", le sens est très proche et plus haut en couleur avec le *marigot* et *curer* renforce l'idée de nettoyage méthodique.
- Oui, beaucoup.

  > - C'est pas le [Pérou](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/c-est-pas-le-perou.php) !
  > - Je veux un [chateau en Espagne](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/chateaux-en-espagne.php).
  > - C'est un peu l'[œil de Moscou](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/l-oeil-de-moscou.php) ce type là !
  > - Ils sont un peu à [la mode de Bretagne](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/a-la-mode-de-bretagne.php)...